# Failing to retrieve Textbox value when Button is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, textbox

Looking at the title it might seem simple but its lil tricky. I am developing a wpf app where I need to dynamically generate button, labels and textbox. In my VoltageView XAml file I have created a stackpanel. In my VoltageChannelView xaml file I have created all the UI components.

I have achieved it to some extent as follows:

**VoltageView:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource styleBackground}" Name="VoltageChannels" >
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Name="stackPanel" Width="Auto" MinHeight="300"></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**VoltageChannelView :**

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ChannelName}" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding VoltageText}" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Set" CommandParameter="{Binding VoltageText}" Command="{Binding VoltageCommand}" />
```

I am adding the above dynamically generated Ui compnents to my stackpanel in my **VoltageView.xaml.cs** as follows:

```
VoltageViewModel mVoltageViewModel = new VoltageViewModel();

// Called in constructor
public void OnChildAdd()
    {            
        foreach (VoltageBoardChannel mVoltageChannelViewModel in mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList)
        {
            VoltageChannelView mVoltageChannelView = new VoltageChannelView();
            mVoltageChannelView.Margin = new Thickness(2);
            mVoltageChannelView.ChannelInfo = mVoltageChannelViewModel;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(mVoltageChannelView);
        }
    }
```

**VoltageViewModel Class:**

```
public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> channelList = null;

    public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> redhookChannels = new ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {             
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_IO_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_CODEC_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_DAL_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_DPD_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_PLL_AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD_AMP1_AUD", IsAvailable = true}             
    };       

    public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> bavaria1Channels = new ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__IO", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__LDO", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__AMP", IsAvailable = true},  

    };        

    public VoltageViewModel()
    {
        channelList = new ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel>();
        channelList = bavaria1Channels;          

    }

    public ObservableCollection<VoltageBoardChannel> VoltageChannelList
    {
        get 
        { 
            return channelList; 
        }

        set
        { 
            channelList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelList");
        }
    }

    RelayCommand _voltageCommand;
    public ICommand VoltageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_voltageCommand == null)
            {
                _voltageCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.DoSomethingExecute, param => this.DoSomethingCanExecute);
            }
            return _voltageCommand;
        }
    }

    public bool DoSomethingCanExecute(object param)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void DoSomethingExecute(object param)
    {

    }
```

As you can see on startup **BAVARIA1** channels are displayed.

**VoltageBoardChannel (Model)Class:**

```
private string mChannelName;
    public string ChannelName
    {
        get
        {
            return mChannelName;
        }
        set
        {
            mChannelName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelName");
        }
    }

    private bool mIsAvailable;
    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get; set;
    }

    string voltageText = string.Empty;
    public string VoltageText
    {
        get
        {
            return voltageText;
        }

        set
        {
            voltageText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VoltageText");
        }
    }
```

Thus when i run the app, it dynamically displays bavaria1 channels 4 times as maintained in the list. Now on each dynamically generated control there is a textbox and button.

You can notice in `VoltageChannelView.xaml` I had done a binding bw Button and textbox. I want to enter value in textbox and on SET button click, it should retrieve the value entered so that further operations can be done. Basically there should be a event for SET button which should pass text written in Textbox as parameter.

How can I achieve it? :)

Comment: where are you setting the VoltageCommand ?

Comment: @Mark:Present in Model class :)

Comment: is the code missing theres only public ICommand VoltageCommand { get; set; } ?

Comment: @Mark: Yes there is only `public ICommand VoltageCommand { get; set; }`. Is their an issue with it? Can you elaborate please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see this right are you missing you're implementation for your Command.
What you need is a logic that handles your Commands .

Copy Source from this article [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051)

**RelayCommand Class**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;        

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;           
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

And your implementation of your Command should than look like:

```
RelayCommand _voltageCommand ;
public ICommand VoltageCommand 
{
    get
    {
        if (_voltageCommand == null)
        {
            _voltageCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DoSomethingExecute,
                this.DoSomethingCanExecute);
        }
        return _voltageCommand;
    }
}
```

**Executemethod:**

```
public void DoSomethingExecute(object param)
{
    // param is your string        
    //Do Something with VoltageText
}
```

**CanExecutemethod**

```
public bool DoSomethingCanExecute(object param)
{
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: I removed VoltageCommand from Model class and added the code you hhave written above. It Throws an error `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` at this.DoSomethingExecute and this.DoSomethingCanExecute. PLus how will I get the text entered in textbox?

Comment: you need also a method for DoSomethingCanExecute if you need it i will update my answer. The Text from VoltageCommand you get in the DoSomethingExecute(object param) the param is your text.

Comment: Can something like this be done: `new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true, VoltageCommand = m_VoltageCommand}` Using This m_voltageCommand, make a delegatecommand and gives me the text entered via some method???

Comment: Yes i added both methods but still it throws the error at `this.DoSomethingExecute`

Comment: did your method look like my example above ? i checked already the code it should be working.

Comment: Yes Mark,its exactly the same.

Comment: than please update your answer with the code where you have placed it. I checked it locally and it s working for me. you need to add the implementation of the command in your ViewModel and the methods are than also there

Comment: have a look at the viewmodel in my question. I have updated it :)

Comment: remove the param => before the methods, i'm sorry :o editet the answer aswell

Comment: Thats k mate :) Well tried it but it doesnt trigger button click at all. I put a breakpoint on `DoSomethingExecute` but no response at all?? has this got something to do with `VoltageCommand` which was part of model class? Currently I have removed it.

Comment: How does `VoltageChannelView.xaml` know that `VoltageCommand` is been used in `VoltageViewModel.cs`??? Have a look at both my xaml's. I think that's the issue

Comment: Soo :o i've now added a full example here https://gist.github.com/3898128 i tested it already and everything is working ;) the only thing what i can think of is that your Binding is not working you can also add an BreakPoint to the get of VoltageCommand and Check if the getter is called.

Comment: How did you Bind your ViewModel to the Datacontext of your xaml ?

Comment: The issue is VoltageViewModel, which is a viewmodel class of VoltageView.xaml. But my `VoltageCommand` is part of VoltageChannelView.xam. Check my xaml files

Comment: I think we need to start a chat soon :P Ok I see does your you can simply add the Command Logic to your VoltageBoardChannel Class otherwise it won't get binded

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18092/discussion-between-stonedjesus-and-mark)